# Back Office Hook isn't running even though its fired

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

So, recently i started to work with Presta and everything on the front office flew perfectly, but in the back office dificulties appeared.

I'm trying to hook to an action *ActionAdminCustomerFormModifier* which is fired in *AdminController.php* like this `Hook::exec('action'.$this->controller_name.'FormModifier', array(...` where `action'.$this->controller_name.'FormModifier` stands for *actionAdminCustomersFormModifier*.

As a good kid i registered it (`$this->registerHook('actionAdminCustomersFormModifier')` like every other hook for front office), created a function in main module class (`public function hookActionAdminCustomersFormModifier`) but, to my horror, it has never run.

I'm using PrestaShop 1.7.4

---

**SOLUTION**

So I just made `public function hookActionAdminFormModifier` and registered it `actionAdminControllerFormModifier` and reuploaded it. My problem was, i think, I had connected my IDE directly to the presta server and probably it had some problems when i registered a new hook. So I have reinstalled my module and everything flew like a charm.

Comment: Are you doing this in module?

Answer (score 0):

In prestashop 1.7 they have updated list of hooks; full list available [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x)

As you are trying to use `hook` named `action<AdminControllerName>FormModifier` and you want to use it for controller `AdminCustomers`; it seems you should use full controller name like `AdminCustomersController` instead.

So you should register your hook first in `install()` method as below;

```
$this->registerHook('actionAdminCustomersControllerFormModifier')
```

and you need to make function named

```
public function hookActionAdminCustomersControllerFormModifier()
```

After making changes please reset your module, so new hook should register itself.

Hope this will be useful for you!